# How to get remaining fraction of data in Data Frame?

Tags: python, pandas

I took a fraction (0.25) of data from Data Frame and named it as positive data , now i want the remaining(0.75) data from same Data Frame . Not sure of how to do it?

Comment: Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the way to do that :

```
train = df.sample(frac = 0.25)
test = df.drop(train.index)
```

This way train will contain 25% of df and test will have the remaining.

Comment: when i use this method , there is some overlapping of x.shape = (640,8) and y.shape = (1000,8) where x and y are two datasets . now , i took a fraction(0.25) of data from "x" and named it as positives [shape = (160,8) and a fraction of data from "y" as negatives (250,8). now when i use df.drop (positives.index) the shape should be (480,8) instead the shape is (501,8). how to solve this problem?